# compiled java program there is no output

Tags: java, awt, frame

Hey guys I'm a total beginner in java programming. Recently I've been referring a book named "Head First Java" to improve my programming skills.when i compile this code there was no error, But there was no output even. What does that mean? Did i do do any mistake in the program? please Help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Party{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame f=new Frame();
        Label l= new Label("party at nick's");
        Button b=new Button("yes!");
        Button c= new Button("no");
        Panel p=new Panel();
        p.add(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Search the web for some tutorials on how to compile and *run* hello world in java.

Comment: You code has nothing to do with Swing, take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You have added `l` Label to `p` Panel.

```
p.add(l);
```

But you have not added anything to `f` Frame.

Try with this:

```
f.add(p);
```

This will add the `p` Panel to the `f` Frame object, so the Label added in Panel can be displayed within the Frame.

To make frame visible you have to set it as visible true.

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

This will make Frame visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `Frame` visible using the `setVisible`-method:

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Also, you are adding the `Label` to the `Panel`, but you also have to

1. add the two buttons to the panel and
2. add the panel to the frame

When adding components to another component, you should also use a layout manager, or set the layout manager to `null` and set the bounds of each component using the `setBounds` method.

*Notice:* AWT is outdated, you should take a look at a [tutorial for Swing](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write code which uses AWT. AWT is a very old and outdated technology. Use Swing instead.

That said, creating a `Frame` isn't enough. You need to make it visible, too:

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Related:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awt/awt_frame.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should execute these statements:

```
Frame f=new Frame();
//specify the layout
f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
Button b=new Button("Dummy button");
Label l=new Label("hello from java");
f.add(l);
f.add(b);
f.setTitle("nick's app");
//specify the size of window
f.setSize(200,200);
//make your frame visible
f.show();
```

Hope this will work... :)